# MKMapView MKTileOverlay erases MKPolyline layer

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpolyline, mktileoverlay

I'm using this SDK for map
https://github.com/2gis/iOS-SDKs-for-tiles
But my added routes is not visible. rendererFor calls, but line is not visible.If i remove  MKTileOverlay everything works fine. How can I fix it ?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

        if (overlay is MKPolyline) {
            let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            pr.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
            pr.lineWidth = 5
            return pr
        } else {
            return MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `MKWebView`?

Comment: El Tomato, thanks. Change title.